# student in training here: glusterfs client can't see its servers

Tags: storage, fileserver, glusterfs

I'm trying to practice a glusterfs setup and when I enter

```
mount -t glusterfs CNAME or IP Address:/volume1/gluster-storage
```

Errors out with : `mount: can't find CNAME or IP Address:/volume1/gluster-storage in /etc/fstab`

the file servers see each other:
Hostname: IPADDRESS
Uuid: system GUID
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)
both show (Connected)
it is just when I try to setup the client connection I hit a wall
what am I missing here?
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created gluster volume and enabled required ports in your firewall.
you can follow these to setup glusterfs
 1.https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
 2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-redundant-storage-pool-using-glusterfs-on-ubuntu-servers
 3. https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-glusterfs-with-a-replicated-volume-over-2-nodes-on-ubuntu-14.04